# Who actually carries out the scheduling in a system

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

I came across that the process ready for execution in the ready queue are given the control of the CPU by the scheduler. The scheduler selects a process based on its scheduling algorithm and then gives the selected process the control of the CPU and later preempts if it is following a preemptive style. I would like to know that if the CPU's processing unit is being used by the processor then who exactly preempts and schedules the processes if the processing unit is not available.

Comment: At a scheduled time, the CPU interupt the current process and gives control to the kernel. From there the scheduler does it's job

Comment: does this happen every time a new process enters the ready queue?And so in a preemptive style, the CPU is used by the kernel every time a process enter the ready queue even if the new process does not qualify for CPU based on the algorithm being followed?

Comment: ..depends on the algorithm.  A new thread might be given a 'one-time-only' priority boost on creation, but that may not get it a core straight off if there are still more, or as many, higher priority ready/running threads than there are cores.

Comment: TBH, your question is not all that clear:(  The scheduler is run when the set of ready/running threads is changed by a syscall or hardware interrupt/driver, so allowing the kernel to be entered and allowing the kernel code to be run.  If there are no syscallls and no interrupts, the kernel code, including it's scheduler/dispatcher, is not executed at all - there is no need for it.

Answer (score 3):

now , i want to share you my thought about the OS,
and I'm sorry my English is not very fluent

What do you think about the OS? Do you think it's 'active'?
no, in my opinion , OS is just a pile of dead code in memory
and this dead code is constituted by interrupt handle function(We just called this dead code 'kernel source code') 
ok, now, CPU is execute process A, and suddenly a 'interrupt' is occur, this 'interrupt' may occured because time clock or because a read system call, anyhow, a interrupt is occur. then **CPU** will jump the constitute  interrupt handl function(CPU jump because CPU's constitute is designed). As said previously, this interrupt handle function is the part of OS kernel source code.
and CPU will execute this code. And what this code will do? **this code will schedule**，and CPU will execute this code.

Comment: Yes, you English is not exactly fluent, but I can understand it, and it didn't stop me upvoting;)

Answer (score 0):

Everything happens in the context of a process (Linux calls these lightweight processes but its the same).

Process scheduling generally occurs either as part of a system service call or as part of an interrupt.

In the case of a system service call, the process may determine it cannot execute so it invokes the scheduler to change the context to a new process.

The OS will schedule timer interrupts where it can do scheduling. Scheduling can also occur in other types of interrupts. Interrupts are handled by the current process.

Comment: 'Interrupts are handled by the current process' no.  Interrupts have no process context.

Comment: That's not true. Every major commercial processor ALWAYS executes in the context of a process. Linux refers to a lightweight process but it is, for all intensive purposes, the context of the process executing before the interrupt (as is the norm with most OSs).

Comment: No.  Interrupt-handlers have no process context.  They are interrupts, triggered by hardware.  The handlers have no idea what process threads may, or may not, be running when they occur.  Maybe we are at cross-purposes here..

Comment: And their address space comes from where?

Comment: Depends on OS, stack from whatever was interrupted plus maybe kernel interupt stack, code from whatever driver, static data from kernel non-swap space.

Comment: Yes, that's the context of the current process.

Comment: Well, I suppose it could be considered as the current process context, mod the different code, stack/frame, data, protection level, memory-management registers etc from whatever process it interrupted. Viewing a hardware interrupt state as a process is.. unusual for me.